# CSV conversion in R for standard calculations

Tags: r, csv, import, mean

I have a problem calculating the mean of columns for a dataset imported from [this CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1xmsk4bh0m24ty/ShimmerData.csv?dl=0)

I import the file using the following command:

```
dataGSR = read.csv("ShimmerData.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=T)
dataGSR$X=NULL #don't need this column
```

Then I take a subset of this

```
dati=dataGSR[4:1000,]
```

i check they are correct

```
head(dati)
  Shimmer Shimmer.1 Shimmer.2        Shimmer.3 Shimmer.4        Shimmer.5 Shimmer.6        Shimmer.7
4   31329         0       713 623.674691281028      2545  3706.5641025641      2409 3529.67032967033
5   31649  9.765625       713 623.674691281028      2526 3678.89230769231      2501 3664.46886446886
6   31969  19.53125       712 638.528829576655      2528 3681.80512820513      2501 3664.46886446886
7   32289 29.296875       713 623.674691281028      2516  3664.3282051282      2498 3660.07326007326
8   32609   39.0625       711  654.10779696494      2503 3645.39487179487      2496 3657.14285714286
9   32929 48.828125       713 623.674691281028      2505 3648.30769230769      2496 3657.14285714286
```

When I type

```
means=colMeans(dati)
Error in colMeans(dati) : 'x' must be numeric
```

In order to solve this problem I convert everything into a matrix

```
datiM=data.matrix(dati)
```

But when I check the new variable, data values are different

```
head(datiM)
    Shimmer Shimmer.1 Shimmer.2 Shimmer.3 Shimmer.4 Shimmer.5 Shimmer.6 Shimmer.7
4     370         1        10         1        65        65         1         1
5     375      3707        10         1        46        46        24        24
6     381      1025         9         2        48        48        24        24
7     386      2162        10         1        36        36        21        21
8     392      3126         8         3        23        23        19        19
9     397      3229        10         1        25        25        19        19
```

My questions here is:

*How to convert correctly the "dati" variable in order to perform the colMeans()?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @akrun's advice, another option is to convert the columns to `numeric` yourself (rather than having `read.csv` do it):

```
dati <- data.frame(
  lapply(dataGSR[-c(1:3),-9],as.numeric))
##
R> colMeans(dati)
   Shimmer  Shimmer.1  Shimmer.2  Shimmer.3  Shimmer.4  Shimmer.5  Shimmer.6  Shimmer.7 
33004.2924 18647.4609   707.4335   718.3989  2521.3626  3672.1383  2497.9013  3659.9287
```

Where `dataGSR` was read in with `stringsAsFactors=F`,

```
dataGSR <- read.csv(
  file="F:/temp/ShimmerData.csv",
  header=TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Unless you know for sure that you need `character` columns to be `factor`s, you are better off setting this option to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

The header lines ("character") in the dataset span first 4 lines.  We could `skip` the 4 lines, use `header=FALSE` and then change the column names based on the info from the first 4 lines.

```
dataGSR <- read.csv('ShimmerData.csv', header=FALSE, 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=4)
lines <- readLines('ShimmerData.csv', n=4)
colnames(dataGSR) <- do.call(paste,  c(strsplit(lines, ','), 
       list(sep="_")))
dataGSR <- dataGSR[,-9]

unname(colMeans(dataGSR))
# [1] 33004.2924 18647.4609   707.4335   718.3989  2521.3626  
#     3672.1383  2497.9013
# [8]  3659.9287
```